# Patched stdin in unittest does not have the string written into it

Tags: python, testing, pytest, python-unittest, sys

If I have a `unittest.TestCase`, I try to patch `sys.stdin` on the function itself:

```py
@patch('sys.stdin', new_callable=StringIO)
def test_bla(mocked_stdin):
   mocked_stdin.write("TEST")

   a = MyClass()
   a.do_stuff_with_stdin()
```

Weirdly enough then if we try to access `sys.stdin` from that class, the string we just wrote is not there to be read:

```py
import sys

def do_stuff_with_stdin():
    r = sys.stdin.read()
    # r = ""
```

But `sys.stdin` has been replaced with a StringIO instance. So the mocking has worked, it's just that the contents are empty.

I am running these tests using `pytest`.

Comment: You need to rewind the pointer to the beginning if you want to read the written text. `mocked_stdin.write("TEST"); mocked_stdin.seek(0); mocked_stdin.read()`

Comment: Thanks, that also explains why it works when the string is passed in on initialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing this down, I figured out one solution, but I'm not sure exactly why this works.

I move the patch into the class and instantiate `StringIO` directly with the data that's supposed to be in there:

```py
with patch('sys.stdin', StringIO(data)):
    a = MyClass()
    a.do_stuff_with_stdin()
```

This seems to work, but I'm a bit flummoxed why that is the case.

**Update:** I get why this works (thanks to [@hoefling's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56933701/patched-stdin-in-unittest-does-not-have-the-string-written-into-it/56933940#comment100408588_56933701) as well), because in this case the StringIO is initialised with a buffer but: “In both cases, the initial file position starts at zero.”